# Laravel Guzzle conflicts with /register Route::auth()

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm new to use Laravel. I'm using Laravel 5.2. I've implemented Auth for user register and login. It is work properly. After installed Guzzle via composer and after that implementing sending email, it works like a charm. But after try to submit register user, the data which sent via POST form, not saved in table. How to keep data recorded in table meanwhile sending email still works?

AuthController for handling user registration:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\PencapaianBadge;
use DB;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|max:10|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        //Ambil id user dengan menhitung jumlah rows
        $id = DB::table('users')->count();

        /*PencapaianBadge::create([
            'id_user' => $id+1,
            'id_badge' => 1,
        ]);*/

        $Pencapaian = new PencapaianBadge();
        $Pencapaian->id_user = $id+2;
        $Pencapaian->id_badge = 1;
        $Pencapaian->save();

        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'role_id' => 2,
            'path_image' => 'main/resources/assets/images/user_profiles/default.png',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: @James Do you mean controller for handling user registration?

Comment: Yes show controller code. And if any error paste it too. No one can  help unless you mention your problem fully.

Comment: @AbhishekChaurasia Ok i get it, already put it on. No error message after submitting, but the data not recorded in table.

Comment: See if User model fillable  array has all the columns name you are trying to insert.

Comment: Data is being saved to PencapaianBadge Table? if not, then check if flow is coming till that point. try to \Log::info('step 1'); at every step and see in laravel log.

Comment: Fillable array already filled with columns name which i need. I've used Log::info as well to trace and the result same as i expected. But the data not stored in users table.